# Is the duration of a power measured on the caster or the recipient?

Tags: savage-worlds

Many powers in Savage Worlds have a duration measured in turns/actions, typically three. Are these turns measured as caster-turns or as recipient-turns?

If duration is measured at the caster, the fact that that [action cards are randomly dealt on each round](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7455/how-long-does-joker-initiative-in-savage-worlds-apply) means that the recipient may benefit from the power for 2, 3, or 4 of their actions. On the other hand, if duration is measured at the recipient, it is unclear whether they benefit before their "first" turn or after their "last" if the caster acts before/after, resulting again in unclear duration of the benefits or penalties.

Answer (score 3):

On [a slightly related thread in the official forum](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41279&sid=fc8d13774b95f233a00c10ca75f867c9), Clint clarifies:

> Duration is based on the caster's actions, not the recipient's
>   actions.

So based on specific initiative order, it is possible for the recipient to get just 2, the average 3, or even 4 rounds of benefit of the power from its base duration. The best deal happens when the recipient acts *after* the caster on turn 0 and *before* the caster on turn 3.

Comment: And remember you can delay initiative, providing some strategic value to turn ordering (since any player can delay their initiative by going on hold).

Comment: That said, I think that if a character on hold doesn't use their action by the time that the cards are redealt, one action should be counted off the duration. You can't keep a three action spell up by delaying for five hours!

Comment: That is correct. If you are dealt a new card, it is assumed that you have done your action... even if that action was doing nothing for six seconds.

Comment: @sergut: Thunderforge's comment is relevant because "A Held action lasts until it’s used. If a character has a Held card when a new round starts, he’s not dealt in." (SW Deluxe, p.65) If you're still on Hold at the end of a round, you _aren't_ dealt a new card.

Comment: After reading the rules carefully, I think delaying initiative does not have an effect at all, because taking a Hold action is an action nonetheless (and can therefore mark the end of a power). See http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27447/continuing-powers-and-hold-action