# Continuing Powers and Hold Action?

Tags: savage-worlds

Say a wizard cast Quickness and it is his third action after it was cast and the wizard does a Hold Action so he can make sure the target gets another action. When does the power end?

a) At the point where the initiative card says the wizard was going to have there action.

b) When the wizard acts (or the end of the round)

I am assuming the the power does not continue into the following rounds if the wizard stays on hold.

Comment: I've always played that it lasts until the wizard actually takes their action or the round ends.  It balances delaying the wizards action with getting an extra round out of a power.  I don't have anything RAW to support this, but it's worked well for us.

Comment: @Toast Though not official, that might be a cool house rule, maybe replacing the existing power maintenance rules.

Answer (score 5):

I would say (a) at **the point where the initiative card says** the wizard starts his "fourth" action, because of two reasons:

**i) To be on Hold is an action.**

> A hero may choose to wait and see what happens by taking a Hold
>   action. He may then go later in the round if he chooses. A Held action
>   lasts until it’s used. [SWD, p65]

What I read here is that the wizard has already acted for a fourth round, and therefore Quickness has ended (unless it is maintained). A Hold action is an action like any other, that takes place on its initiative card like any other; the only difference is that it allows the character to interrupt other characters that act later (even in future rounds).

**ii) The opposite interpretation can result in absurd situations.**

> If a character has a Held card when a new round starts, he’s not dealt
>   in.  [SWD, p65]

If a power lasted until "the wizard acts", that would mean that a power can last forever as long as the wizard was on Hold. I do not think this makes any sense.

**Update:** This was briefly mentioned in another recent [question about the duration of powers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27360/is-the-duration-of-a-power-measured-on-the-caster-or-the-recipient/27361).

**Update:** thanks to Toast, we can see that [Clint said the same thing](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41376) in the official forums some time ago:

> The power lasts until their action comes up. Choosing to perform a Hold action and wait till later to do something
>   doesn't alter the fact that their action came up to make that choice.

Comment: Agreed. The point about being On Hold counting as an action is the important bit.

Answer (score 3):

The power should end when the wizard's action first comes up, regardless of if they go on hold or not.

See Clint's answer here:  http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41376